# Accessing all images in a folder with incremental names

Tags: python-3.x, image, directory, python-imaging-library

I am trying to write a program where I will crop and then rotate every image inside a folder. I am currently able to do it for a single image and I know I can manually type them all in. But I would like to know how I can loop it where I can run my code multiple times since there are about 500 pictures. Also, I am running Python3 on windows.

```
from PIL import Image

# Convert coordinate list into variables
print("Type in the coordinates for the upper left (x1,y1) and bottom right (x2,y2) points")
coordinates = list(map(int, input("Separate values with a space (x1 y1 x2 y2): ").strip().split()))[:4]
x1, y1, x2, y2 = coordinates
print("Generating image...")

# Accessing file from folder
im = Image.open("C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\Ps\\2.tiff")

# Cropping function
selected_region = (x1, y1, x2, y2)
cropped_region = im.crop(selected_region)

# If cropped area is vertical, rotate into horizontal position
if (y2 - y1) > (x2 - x1):
    rotated_image = cropped_region.rotate(90, expand=1) 
else:
    rotated_image = cropped_region # Does nothing is image is horizontal

# Saving image to a new folder
rotated_image.save("C:\\Users\\Alex\Desktop\\Ps\\Output\\rotated.tiff", quality=95)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using `pathlib`. This snippet of code defines `p` to be the `Path` shown. Then the loop provides each file name in that folder.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path('C:/Camera/Children and yard/')
>>> for item in p.glob('*.jpg'):
...     item.name
```

In response to question: To obtain the complete path to a file you can use `as_posix()`. Thus, part of what you need would be ...

```
im = Image.open(item.as_posix())
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but, how would I then call each image to apply the crop function. If it helps, each of my photos are named test1.tiff, test2.tiff... Thank you.

Comment: Please see addition to answer.

Comment: I think I finally got it to work. Thank you for all the help.